# No se cambia la variable en Kotlin

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

tengo un String que obtengo correctamente de firebase, el problema es que cuando intento asignar ese String a una variable, esto no se realiza correctamente.
Este es mi codigo, en este caso mi variable palabra es igual a un "hola", pero luego le asigno un string diferente pero el cambio no acurre ya que sigue imprimiendo "hola".

```
val db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
        var palabra: String? = "hola"
        db.collection("videos").document("listadevideos").get().addOnSuccessListener {
            println(it.get("video"))  //imprime en consola correctamente el string
            palabra = it.get("video") as String?

       
        }
        println(palabra) //imprime hola en lugar de el string que asigne
```

Saben que esta pasando? y como puedo hacer para que se cambio la variable como deseo.
Gracias por su atención.

Answer (score 0):

eso es porque el último print se ejecuta inmediatamente después de hacer la consulta y en ese punto la consulta todavía no devolvió un resultado. En cambio lo que está adentro de `addOnSuccessListener` es un callback que se ejecuta una vez que la consulta fue exitosa.

Te recomiendo usar una [suspend function](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/composing-suspending-functions.html)

```
suspend fun esperarResultado(): String? = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
    .collection("videos").document("listadevideos").get().await().getString("video")
```

Esta función usa `await()` para esperar que la consulta termine y luego retorna el resultado. Como es una `suspend function` debes llamarla desde un [CoroutineScope](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-coroutine-scope/index.html):

```
CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
    val palabra = esperarResultado()
    println(palabra)
}
```

En ese ejemplo estoy creando mi propio scope pero android ya tiene definidos unos [lifecycle-aware scopes](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/coroutines#lifecycle-aware) que son `lifecycleScope` (presente en Activity y Fragment) y `viewModelScope` (presente en la clase ViewModel). Entonces si estás en una activity deberías llamar `lifecycleScope.launch{...}`.

Cabe mencionar que no es necesario crear la suspend function. Dentro de `launch` también puedes usar `await` pero en ese caso no habría mucha diferencia con escribir todo dentro de un callback como en tu ejemplo inicial.

Firestore, al igual que todas las APIs de google, devuelve un objeto [Task](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/tasks#kotlin_coroutine) en todas las operaciones asíncronas. Esta clase tiene 3 metodos principales:

- `addOnSuccessListener`: agrega un callback que se ejecuta sólo si la operacion fue exitosa
- `addOnFailureListener`: agrega un callback que se ejecuta cuando la operacion falla
- `addOnCompleteListener`: agrega un callback que se ejecuta en ambos casos

Las [kotlin coroutines](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/coroutines) nos permiten reemplazar todos los callbacks usando [await](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-play-services/kotlinx.coroutines.tasks/com.google.android.gms.tasks.-task/await.html) y un [try catch](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/exceptions.html)

```
try {
    task.await()
    // success listener
} catch (e: Exception) {
    // failure listener
} finally {
    // complete listener
}
```