# Modificar variables en proceso asincrono

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin

obtengo un string desde firebase, y luego asigno ese String a una variable.
El problema esta en que al parecer  la variable no se asigna a tiempo, ya que esta en un proceso asincrono, eso es lo que dedusco.
Como puedo hacer para que la variable se asigne como deseo, es decir que al final el print termine imprimiendo, el string que obtengo de firebase.

```
val db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
        var palabra: String? = "hola"
        db.collection("videos").document("listadevideos").get().addOnSuccessListener {
            println(it.get("video"))  //imprime correctamente el string
            palabra = it.get("video") as String?

       
        }
        println(palabra) //imprime hola en lugar de el string que asigne
```

Comment: Soy nuevo en kotlin, en otros lenguajes ahi una funcion llamada yield, la cual tiene un parametro que es un tiempo en segundos, esta permite detener el codigo durante ese tiempo por los segundos que le indicaste, cuando se llega a esa linea, luego continua leyendo el codigo, podria usar algo asi para esperar a que el valor se asigne y luego que continue leyendo el codigo, existe algo asi en kotlin, o talvez una solucion compatible con kotlin.

Comment: Esta pregunta es duplicada. Es la misma que [esta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/419293/no-se-cambia-la-variable-en-kotlin)

Comment: Hola, disculpe si es la misma, pude entender cual era el problema pero lamentablemente la solucion no funciono, por ello la rescribi de forma mas clara, para que se entienda mejor el problema y talves aya una nueva solucion.

Comment: La solución debe funcionar porque es exactamente el mismo código, letra por letra...  Imprime "hola" porque la callback ***NO SE EJECUTÓ AUN***. Esa función donde asignas el string, NO sabes **CUANDO SE EJECUTARÁ**, puesto que es una llamada a los servidores de firebase, y tendrán que devolverte el valor y viajar de nuevo hasta tu dispositivo. Todo ese tiempo de viaje de tu dispositivo al servidor y vuelta, es muchísimo más que lo que tarda en ejecutarse la siguiente línea de código, así que obviamente, la siguiente línea de código se ejecuta ***ANTES*** que esa asignación.

Comment: @Yamz edité mi respuesta en la otra pregunta para explicar mas cosas. Tal vez ahora te sirva. No sé si debería duplicarla acá pero es cierto que tu pregunta está mejor explicada y titulada

Comment: hola puedes usar esta libreria implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-play-services:1.1.1'
y te perimite bloquear una peticion utilizando un await asi primero se termina de ejecutar un peticion yluego sigue a la siguiente es parte de las librerias kotlin-ktx